# PHP - Sort array value reverse alphabetically and echo output string

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

**Input Array**

```
$userArr = array("0"=>"Veronica", "1"=>"Alex", "2"=>"Joe", "3"=>"Alex", "4"=>"Veronica");
```

Here, user `Veronica` and `Alex` are repeated twice. How do I sort above array reverse alphabetical way even if count of two users are same i.e. `Veronica => 2, Alex => 2`, only `Veronica` will be displayed as output string.

```
$userArr = array("0"=>"Veronica", "1"=>"Alex", "2"=>"Joe", "3"=>"Alex", "4"=>"Veronica");
$userCnt = array_count_values($userArr);
foreach ($userCnt as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
Veronica
```

Comment: Still not sure I understand, but there's a lot of options now.

Comment: Did you give up or what?

Comment: Why do you only expect Veronica if there is a tie for most occurrences?  Your question and [mcve] are unclear.

Answer (score 0):

**Your Input Array:**

```
$userArr = array("0"=>"Veronica", "1"=>"Alex", "2"=>"Joe", "3"=>"Alex", "4"=>"Veronica");
```

**Count of an array:**

```
echo count($userArr);
```

**Reverse of an array:**

```
arsort($userArr);
print_r($userArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$userArr = array(
        "0"=>"Veronica", 
        "1"=>"Alex", 
        "2"=>"Joe", 
        "3"=>"Alex", 
        "4"=>"Veronica");

//below line will first create an associative array with 
//values as keys and their count as the value...
$arrayVals = array_count_values($userArr);

//next we sort this array in reverse alphabetically... 
krsort($arrayVals);

//finally, print it :)
print_r($arrayVals);

//will print...
Array
(
  [Veronica] => 2
  [Joe] => 1
  [Alex] => 2
)
```

---

UPDATE: Based on OP's explanation,I think he wants the value of the "last" alphabetical word in the array. If that is the case, the following code should do the trick:

```
$userArr = array("0"=>"Veronica", "1"=>"Alex", "2"=>"Joe", "3"=>"Alex", "4"=>"Veronica");
rsort($userArr);
echo current($userArr);
```

Comment: Only `Veronica` should be displayed as output string.

Comment: Then just echo the first item  echo $arrayVals[0];

Comment: If you add `Xavier ` to the list then it will first even though there is only 1 and it should still be `Veronica`.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy: I am sorry, I do not understand your requirement. Do you want only the first item to be printed? Do you want the first item that has a count > 2? Do you just plain want "Veronica" to be printed? Not getting what you are trying to do here...

Comment: I might rephrase the question but the output should print any name that comes last alphabetically in a given array.For example Vernonica appears twice and alex also appeara twice, but it should print Vernonica as output string coz it comes last if sorted alphabet in desc order

Comment: This makes even less sense now.  `Veronica` will be last whether there are 1 or 2 or 3 etc.. And it will be last no matter how many times `Alex` appears.  Why use `array_count_values()`?

Answer (score 0):

Using your approach, I'm assuming you want the one with the highest count that is also the last alphabetically:

```
$userArr = array("0"=>"Veronica", "1"=>"Alex", "2"=>"Joe", "3"=>"Alex", "4"=>"Veronica");
$userCnt = array_count_values($userArr);

ksort($userCnt);

$count = 0;
foreach ($userCnt as $key => $val) {
    if($val >= $count) {
        $result = $key;
        $count  = $val;
    }
}
echo "$result appeared $count times";
```

- Count the values
- Sort by key (names)
- Loop and check if the count (`$val`) is greater or equal to the last one

It seems to be even simpler with your new comments.  Sort the original and grab either the first or last depending on sort order:

```
rsort($userArr);
echo current($userArr);
//or
sort($userArr);
echo end($userArr);
```

If you need the `array_count_values()` for whatever reason:

```
$userCnt = array_count_values($userArr);
krsort($userCnt);
echo key($userCnt);
```